# Can't reference a related table in Yii's ActiveRecord

Tags: yii

I'm trying to get a related table in Yii and it keeps giving me an error trying to reference the event.text field.

```
return new CActiveDataProvider( 'InvitationCode', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
    'select' => array( 't.id', 'code', 'Event.text' ),
    'condition'=>'t.id >= :min_code_id AND t.id <= :max_code_id',
    'order'=>'t.id Asc',
    'with' => array( 'Event' ),
    'params' => array(
          ':min_code_id' => $min_code_id, 
          ':max_code_id' => $max_code_id,
        ),                  
    ),      
));
```

The table event which is related to InvitationCode through the relation 'Event' does have a text field, but I can't access it with either 'event.text' nor 'Event.text'
If I leave the 'select' part out, it only brings the fileds of InvitationCode and none of the fields from the related table Event despite it's in the 'with' part.

How can I reference the related table Event?

Comment: just guessing, what if you also use `'together'=>true` in the criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the exact error message?
Can you post the code defining relations() in InvitationCode model class?
Did you enable query logging to see the exact query generated?

As the comment noted, you probably have to explicitly set together=>true for eager loading.

From: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

> **together**: whether the table associated with this relationship should
>   be forced to join together with the primary table and other tables.
>   This option is only meaningful for HAS_MANY and MANY_MANY relations.
>   If this option is set false, the table associated with the HAS_MANY or
>   MANY_MANY relation will be joined with the primary table in a separate
>   SQL query, which may improve the overall query performance since less
>   duplicated data is returned. If this option is set true, the
>   associated table will always be joined with the primary table in a
>   single SQL query, even if the primary table is paginated. If this
>   option is not set, the associated table will be joined with the
>   primary table in a single SQL query only when the primary table is not
>   paginated. For more details, see the section "Relational Query
>   Performance".